# Azure VM not starting

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I had an Azure VM whenever I clicked on start it is stopping automatically after some time when I run diagnose it is showing this error   "A reboot was triggered from inside the virtual machine. This could be due to a virtual machine operating system failure or as requested by an authorized user or process. The virtual machine will be back online after the reboot completes"
Plz let me know if you need any further inforamtion

Comment: Is this helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/understand-vm-reboot

Comment: @NancyXiong I checked that but it didn't solve!!

Comment: @Develpoer_J - did the below solution helped you fix the problem? If so, please mark the answer as accepted so that it helps others in the community as well.

Answer (score 1):

The request to start a Stopped VM in Azure (or any Cloud Service Provider, for that matter) has to be attempted at the original Cluster in the Data-center that hosts those resources. And if that Cluster doesn't have any free space available to fulfill the request, the VM might not get back up and running.

A resolution could be to stop all the VMs in that Availability Set, and restart each VM one by one by following these steps:

- Go to "Resource Groups" in Azure Portal
- Select your Resource Group
- Under the list of Resources in your RG, select your Availability Set resource
- Go to the "Virtual Machines" blade
- Stop each VM one by one and start them up again.